# How do we handle AI-generated answers?

Tags: discussion, moderation, answers

**Background.** StackOverflow has recently published a [policy update](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy) concerning the AI-generated answers specifically mentioning GPT and ChatGPT. The policy notes that current AI-generated contributions are failing to

- validate the answer is correct,
- cite sources used in the answer, and
- verify the answer clearly and concisely answers the question.

The policy considers these failures a trust issue and empowers moderators to use their discretion to issue immediate suspensions of up to 30 days to violators. (with or without warning).

**Discussions from related SE sites:**

StackOverflow

- [Temporary policy: ChatGPT is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/8239061)
- [What should I do if I suspect that a question or answer is written by ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421988/8239061)

Math.SE

- [What is our policy on AI-generated content?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35342/572874)
- [Are the machines upon us?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28528/572874)

CrossValidated (Stats.SE)

- [What to do about answers written by ChatGPT](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6422/177387)

DataScience.SE

- [On AI-generated answers](https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2637/54678)

MathOverflow

- [ChatGPT strikes MathOverflow](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5531)

Academia.SE

- [Automatically-generated text is banned on Academia.SE](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5225/94518)

Physics.SE

- [Please don't use computer-generated text for questions or answers on Physics](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14281)

Quantum Computing SE

- [What should be our default policy in ChatGPT-provided answers?](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/583)

Artificial Intelligence

- [Please do not post AI-generated content as actual posts](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2905/66680)

Uber-Meta

- [Ban ChatGPT network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384396/476162)
- [How can we enforce the ChatGPT ban?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384457/476162)
- [How often does ChatGPT give an incorrect answer to an SE question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384410/476162)
- [Is there a list of ChatGPT discussions and policies for our sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384922/476162)

---

**Q:  How should OR.SE handle AI-generated answers?**

Comment: I believe the OR.SE community is small enough that this is currently not an issue. IMO the voting system in place and the level of activity of e.g. high rep users seem sufficient to identify any such answers in the future.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Agreed.

Comment: Apparently there is now an OR.SE AI Policy:  https://or.stackexchange.com/help/ai-policy